# What has changed that cloistered catholic monks (as communities) are not advancing technical sciences and engineering today?

Tags: works, monasticism

Cistercians and other catholic monks are notorious for the introduction of the advancements in technical sciences and agriculture in the Medieval ages. But I recently saw movie about Athon monks (Orthodox, not catholic) https://denpeirazei.com/ and also I am seeing Benedictine abbeys near and far from me. And all of them are adept at keeping guesthouses, doing mean agricultural works and producing food products and beverages. Usually they use almost a hypocritical mix of technologies and handwork. Actually such small-scale businesses could hardly survive without the donations.

My desire is to find the monastic community that advances Artificial Intelligence, robotics and automation of jobs because precisely those advances free human beings from the oppression by each other and hence - precisely those technologies (of course, if only properly managed and put into the right socio-economic mechanisms) eradicate poverty. Hence - this is the ultimate job that the communities of work and prayer can do, in my humble opinion, this is the ultimate job. But I have not found such communities. Only advanced communities are the hospital chains managed by quasi-monastic sisters, those chains can have advanced medical research cultures indeed. Catholic universities are another story, especially Leuven in Belgium and Notre Dame in the US. But still, they are not monastic communities, even if monks are sitting in the boards of trustees and department chairs.

So - what has changed that this passion for technical advancement has ceased and are there Catholic monastic movements to reignite this passion for technical innovation?

*Clarification added*: It is quite possible that monks are doing research work as individual researchers and collaborate with some lay or monastic persons. My question was about communities specifically. E.g. almost sure that someone is required a community to build a robot, some is required a community (small, but still) to advance AI models or cognitive architecture.

*Additional clarification added*: Some argue (e.g. in the comments) that my question is of sociological and historical nature. I.e. effectively they are trying to say (without giving explanation, sources and argumentation) that changes in monastic tradition, customs and nature are always of sociological and historical nature and that changes can not be due to the development of the spiritual practices, theological understanding and related schools of thoughts that consider monastic life in the light of theology and pastoral theology. My feeling is that my question calls for the wider deconstruction of the monastic life and the spiritual components of this destruction can be considered in this site as part of my question.

Comment: Technical sciences and engineering is secondary to a monks primary studies. The primary studies would naturally be of a theological nature: God, the sacraments, holiness and so on.

Comment: I don't see any facts here, only opinions.

Comment: @NigelJ I agree. TomR doesn't substantiate his claim that "monks are not advancing technical sciences and engineering today". The question is also half seeking pastoral advice / vocational guidance.

Comment: It is hard to prove 'NOT' case. I searched google for abbey, monastic communities, etc. which develop AI and robotics and nothing comes up. I listed already Universities and hospital chains. I have some point. In medieval ages monks did their best - best illuminated manuscripts, best agricultural work, best painting work. Today I see the film about Athon, I see the youtube movies about my neigbouring Benedictine abbey and I know that I can not do such dull work in the time that Benedictines are required to devote for work. I just don't see the sense of doing work without...

Comment: ...available up-to-date technologies and state-of-art and denote such job as holy, rewarding and meaningful. Yes, in the world some are required to do such kind of jobs because of economic situations. But in somewhat ideal communities it is incomprehensible. Today's work involves innovation, every bright company tries to do R&D and tries to innovate what their are doing. So, the monastic communities that devote some time for work should innovate and advance as well.

Comment: I am not talking about studies. I am talking about what monks are doing in their time that is set aside for work by monastic regulations. Contemporary work includes R&D and innovation.

Comment: @Geremia I would be very thankful and I would include You in my prayers if you could point to some monastic community that is advancing such technical sciences. I would be happy to consider it for my plans in one or other form.

Comment: E.g. Google query 'catholic monastery is building a robot' first 4 pages gives no single suggestion.

Comment: I see the value of this question after reviewing the technological advancement that [Cisternians did 1000 years ago](https://www.uh.edu/engines/epi1311.htm) so they could achieve economic independence, save time so they can pray and copy scriptures, and even benefit society with the technology!  But I think this is a *sociological* / *historical* question, not a spiritual diagnosis / indictment question.  Hence my vote to close.

Comment: @TomR  Please consider that now 1000 years later the situation has much changed: the society at large is much more educated and technology becomes a lot more specialized requiring tenured professors that you can no longer do both philosophy+theology track *AND* be at the cutting edge of the technology at the same time.  Helping the world to be closer to God **IS** their primary service to society, which shouldn't be abandoned if they have to choose one.

Comment: An excellent point, @GratefulDisciple. I feel the questioner’s passion for technology - but in this day and age you would need to choose.. I’m also not convinced about the social benefits of robotics, by the way.. Apple just recently got rid of 60k employees and replaced them with robots.. every truck driver’s job is under threat.. that’s millions of people. What are they going to do now? The role and function of a community will surely, more and more, be to take us back to a simpler way of life, not a more complex, modernist one?

Comment: @TomR, on a different track though, no doubt you are engaging with the Jesuit order on this? Also have you considered working for / applying for (I don’t quite know how it works!) Vatican City? They have an astronomy centre. You could take your background in AI and ML and apply it there? Another point: I don’t think the vocational net is currently being cast in this direction.. unless that changes, you are unlikely to see large numbers of brothers and sisters sharing your passion for AI-driven robotics. My final point would be that even if you found something big to be a part of, …

Comment: … you would still only ever play a small role in that big organisation, right? So it’s important to discover which is more important: the community or the work… it’s not likely to be both at this point in history, given your interests.

Comment: *What has changed that cloistered catholic monks (as communities) are not advancing technical sciences and engineering today?* - The somewhat obvious answer is *technical sciences and engineering*, which, centuries ago, were in such a precarious state, that even humble monks could contribute something meaningful to their advance; nowadays, they are so developed, that even many [STEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science,_technology,_engineering,_and_mathematics) graduates fail to.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple My guess is that everyone should try (at least try) to do work with the current technology and according to the current best practices. My mentioned movie about Athos monastic community raises great doubts that monastic communities are serous about best practices. They consider the work as just some form of suffering and not the serious business that requires innovating, establishing and following the best practices. This is spiritual question of some kind - is it work just suffering or does work have some ethic and standards that currently include innovation and...

Comment: ... and creativity as well. I remember medieval story about some monks: chief monk saw that some monks are idle and he required them to move stones from one place to another. When it has been done, then he required move them back. The rationale: idleness is sin or leads to sin. But instead monks could innovate in that time, create something new, always that can be done. Or at least - they could learn to innovate if they lacked skills... Well - after seeing that Athos movie I have some big, big reservations about monasticism I just could not express it clearly. My bad.

Comment: Have you read A Canticle for Leibowitz?  Maybe the question isn't "what has changed"? but "what would need to change?"?

Answer (score 2):

**What has changed that cloistered catholic monks are not advancing technical sciences and engineering today?**

The schools of higher education are no longer restricted to monastic institutions. At one time, in Christendom, the monastery was almost the only form of education in Medieval Europe. Not today!

Many monastic orders developed over the years. In medieval Western Europe, monks spent their days praying and working. Their work would entail either writing or performing physical labor to maintain their home and grounds. Those who were literate would copy important texts to preserve them.

Until the High Middle Ages, monasteries were dominant centers for education. The High Middle Ages spanned from around the 11th century to the 13th century. Leading up to this time, the Catholic Church had become the dominant religion in Western Europe.

> The university is generally regarded as a formal institution that has its origin in the Medieval Christian setting. Prior to the establishment of universities, European higher education took place for hundreds of years in Christian cathedral schools or monastic schools (***scholae monasticae***), in which monks and nuns taught classes. Evidence of these immediate forerunners of the later university at many places dates back to the 6th century AD.
>
> With the increasing growth and urbanization of European society during the 12th and 13th centuries, a demand grew for professional clergy. Before the 12th century, the intellectual life of Western Europe had been largely relegated to monasteries, which were mostly concerned with performing the liturgy and prayer; relatively few monasteries could boast true intellectuals. Following the Gregorian Reform's emphasis on canon law and the study of the sacraments, bishops formed cathedral schools to train the clergy in Canon law, but also in the more secular aspects of religious administration, including logic and disputation for use in preaching and theological discussion, and accounting to control finances more effectively. Pope Gregory VII was critical in promoting and regulating the concept of modern university as his 1079 Papal Decree ordered the regulated establishment of cathedral schools that transformed themselves into the first European universities.
>
> Learning became essential to advancing in the ecclesiastical hierarchy, and teachers also gained prestige. Demand quickly outstripped the capacity of cathedral schools, each of which was essentially run by one teacher. In addition, tensions rose between the students of cathedral schools and burghers in smaller towns. As a result, cathedral schools migrated to large cities, like Bologna, Rome and Paris.
>
> Syed Farid Alatas has noted some parallels between Madrasahs and early European colleges and has thus inferred that the first universities in Europe were influenced by the Madrasahs in Islamic Spain and the Emirate of Sicily. George Makdisi, Toby Huff and Norman Daniel, however, have questioned this, citing the lack of evidence for an actual transmission from the Islamic world to Christian Europe and highlighting the differences in the structure, methodologies, procedures, curricula and legal status of the "Islamic college" (madrasa) versus the European university. - [Medieval university](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_university)

Today, secular universities outnumber both monastic and other religious universities combined. What started out as monastic schools of higher education has been taken over by secular universities.

Some monastic communities may still make advancements in technical sciences and engineering, natural sciences such as in agriculture today, but they are less well known.

Take the example of beekeeping at [**Buckfast Abbey**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckfast_Abbey)

> **Beekeeping**
>
> Buckfast Abbey monastic produce shop
> [**Brother Adam**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Kehrle) (born Karl Kehrle in 1898 in Germany, died in 1996) was put in charge of the Abbey's beekeeping in 1919, and began extensive breeding work creating the honeybee now known as the [**Buckfast bee**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckfast_bee). Brother Adam had to replenish the bee colonies as 30 of the monastery's 46 colonies had been wiped out by a disease known at the time as the Isle of Wight Disease, but later called "Acarine", all the bees that died were of the indigenous Old British Black bee (a now extinct British strain of the [**A. m. mellifera**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_dark_bee)). The 16 hives that survived were of Italian Ligurian origin (A. m. ligustica). At the request of the government, Brother Adam helped in restocking the British Isles with his disease resistant **Buckfast bees**. Today the breeding of pedigree **Buckfast bees** is regulated by the Federation of European Buckfast Beekeepers (G.D.E.B.) in over twenty six countries with numerous breeders.

We should always keep in mind that technical sciences and engineering is secondary to a monks primary studies. The primary studies would naturally be of a theological nature: God, the sacraments, holiness and so on. A monk’s primary concern is the contemplation of things Divine.

Other influences that added to the move from the monastic styled school universities to state universities were the introduction of the printing press, the use of the vernacular language instead of Latin and the now famous **Reformation**.

In modern times, the Jesuit Order seems to have taken up the studies of technical scientific studies and monks have returned to their original way of theological studies.

Take the [**Vatican Observatory**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatican_Observatory) as an example.

> The Vatican Observatory (Italian: Specola Vaticana) is an astronomical research and educational institution supported by the Holy See. Originally based in the Roman College of Rome, the Observatory is now headquartered in Castel Gandolfo, Italy and operates a telescope at the Mount Graham International Observatory in the United States.
>
> The Director of the Observatory is Brother Guy Consolmagno, an American Jesuit. In 2008, the Templeton Prize was awarded to cosmologist Fr. Michał Heller, a Vatican Observatory Adjunct Scholar. In 2010, the George Van Biesbroeck Prize was awarded to former observatory director, the American Jesuit, Fr. George Coyne.

[image: Mount Graham International Observatory]

[Mount Graham International Observatory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Graham_International_Observatory)